# SQL Statement 'Missing Parameter' Fails On Single Machine

Tags: sql

I'm using vb.net, and I've created a sql statement that I use with a OleDBConnection object.  When I run my sql (below) the ExecuteReader throws an error (also below).  The problem is that it works on the 50+ en-US machines that it's run on, but now I've got my first client in Germany, and it fails on their machine.  I set my dev machine to German settings to try to replicate the issue, but it works just fine for me.  I copied-over their exact data file and it works on my machine.  So seemingly it has to do with it being a non en-US machine?

Here is the SQL statement:

```
SELECT Val(IIf(IsNumeric([Sequence]), [Sequence], '0')), * 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY SomeOtherField, 1
```

So in short, I want to order by the sequence column secondarily, but in the event that Sequence isn't numeric I'll just give it a '0' so that it allows the sort to take place based on the dynamic column '1' I am creating/selecting on-the-fly.

Here is the error on the German machine:
Fuer mindestens einen erforderlichen Parameter wurde kein Wert angegeben.
(Roughly translated:  For at least one required parameter was not specified value)

Does anyone have any ideas as to what my issue might be?  Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide to me.

-Greg

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess.  But, try replacing the iif() with a case statement:

```
SELECT (case when IsNumeric([Sequence]) = 1 then [Sequence]
             else '0'
        end),
       mt.* 
FROM MyTable mt
ORDER BY SomeOtherField, 1
```

I suspect that your other systems are using Access, and the German system is using SQL Server.  SQL Server does not recognize iif.